# Controlling Arduino through public internet

Tags: embedded, arduino, communication, gprs

I am thinking of controlling an Arduino over the Internet.

Say I don't have a static IP connection to my Arduino (I am using a GPRS shield.) In such situations I have to follow a procedure something like this. Suppose I am trying to on/off a single device through web.

1. There is a web site with a domain name hosted on a server. There is
   a PHP web page and an associated MySQL table to hold ON/OFF
   commands.
2. When a user needs to turn on the device he sends a
   specific request to PHP page. It changes a flag stored in a table in
   database.
3. The arduino sends requests periodically to web page to ask
   whether there is any update. The PHP page checks the database and
   respond to arduino so now the arduino can turn on/off the device
   accordingly.

My Questions are,

1. Running a (web) server in Arduino might be another approach. But can I access it from public internet? I am using a GPRS module. Does the mobile service subscribers allow incoming connections?
2. To get a realtime output I have to send requests continuously with a very short dalay. And the PHP page has to query the database again and again. Performance wise this is not a good approach. What are the alternatives I have in this case? (I am using a database since I am planning to have many users with many devices.)
3. What are the alternate approaches I have to implement the same?

Comment: Interesting project! 1.) Talk to your mobile operator re Internet access. I assume you have to register it before allowed access to the cellular network? My guess is it is quite possible. But why not bypass the web server and control the Arduino from a phone? 2.) Polling from the Arduino is not a good approach in my view. Better to send commands to the Arduino. 3.) Remote over internet to home computer (remote desktop connection), home computer to Arduino over WiFi or radio (xbee etc). My setup is application on laptop, XBEE to Arduino. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you might consider is connecting from arduino to server using a client socket on the arduino end and then when an update occurs the server can just push the update to the socket the arduino is listening on.  This would allow for realtime instant updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Raspberry Pi instead? You can control 8 GPIO pins (general purpose I/O, like the Arduino) which is enough for most applications.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question specifically stated that he wanted to accomplish this with Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why you are using a GPRS shield. Some things to consider using the basic setup you outlined:

- The wisdom on the Internets is that by default incoming GPRS connections are disabled but can be enabled. If this is true then a) you might get a static IP b) you might get a hostname which will resolve to your Arduino device or c) you can (in the worst case) uses dynamic DNS services like noip.com and similar.
- I disagree with other posters that polling is such a *terrible* idea. If you are smart about your architecture then polling for *new data only* should not cause intensive traffic. What I am saying is that your intermediary server should only send data to the Arduino that the Arduino hasn't seen before. In this case the only extra traffic associated with polling the handshaking/protocol traffic, not the data. On the back end, the server might preprocess the data to be sent to Arduino while waiting for the next poll request. The point is the only disadvantes of polling relative to push should be a) potential time lag and b) extra data wasted making the connection. If you can find an acceptable answer to a), b) shouldn't be a very big deal.

If you are willing to consider other ways of connecting your Arduino to the internet as [user2019047](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019047/user2019047) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331350/controlling-arduino-through-public-internet#comment23391111_16331350) there are many ways to think about:

- Mobile. Maybe your link can use telephony, at least in part: say your server notified the Arduino that there is new data to be picked up via SMS, or a telephone call from a particular number?
- You could link your Arduino with a PC via XBee, serial, Bluetooth, or some other wireless or wired technology. Then the PC connected to Arduino could communicate with your server that your users talk to.